# How to fix Cannot find module './aws-export' or its corresponding type declarations.ts (2307)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native

I am trying  to integrate my project with aws (amazon web service )
After I initialize aws globally I decided to create a project  call ELab by using the

following command

```
amplify init
```

and also using the following command to configure it

```
npm install aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-react
```

then I add this to my App.tsx file

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify'
import config from './aws-exports' // error the /aws-exports.js was not generated
Amplify.configure(config)
```

After all those configuration aws fail to generate the aws-exports.js configuration file

is there any to resolve this issues thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

You can rename aws-exports.js to aws-exports.ts.

There is a drawback. Amplify would re-generate the JavaScript version (aws-exports.js) each time, and you would have to manually rename it. Not ideal, and there is an open issue on this: [github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/304](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/304)

**Option 2**

You can also create a aws-exports.d.ts file on the same level as aws-exports with the following content:

```
declare const awsmobile: Record<string, any>
export default awsmobile;
```

See more [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/angular/#strictly-typing-aws-exports).

Comment: This caused me some trouble because aws does export its settings when running`amplify push` to aws-exports.js after all. This causes the data in your .ts file to be stale, which entailed some problems in my case.

Comment: Yes, that is a drawback It would be ideal if Amplify can export the .ts file each time. There is an open issue on this: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/304

Answer (score 1):

See this doc

https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/angular/#install-amplify-libraries

Strictly typing aws-exports
If you have TypeScript strict mode on and see the error

Create a aws-exports.d.ts file on the same level as aws-exports with the following content:

```
declare const awsmobile: Record<string, any>
export default awsmobile;
```

Comment: You can rename aws-exports.js to aws-exports.ts. It worked for me.